# Pyspark String to Decimal Conversion along with precision and format like Java decimal formatter

Tags: python, pyspark, decimal, user-defined-functions

I am trying to convert String to decimal.
I may receive decimal data as below sometimes 
**1234.6789-** (- at the end) 
In java i can specify format like below  to parse above ,
**DecimalFormat dfmt = new DecimalFormat("0000.0000;0000.0000-")** so that i get decimal value as -1234.6789

do we have equivalent in Python or Pyspark like above

I have created UDF

```
def getDecimalVal(myString):
    return Decimal(myString)
ConvertToDec = udf(getDecimalVal, DecimalType(4))
```

I am invoking this in my below code

```
Employee = Row("firstName", "lastName", "email", "salary","salaryday")
employee1 = Employee('steve', 'mill', 'bash@elean.co', "0012.7590","2020-04-30")
employee2 = Employee( 'jack','neil', 'daniel@ssl.edu', "0013.2461","2020-04-30" )
employees=[employee1,employee2]
dframe = spark.createDataFrame(employees)
dframe=dframe.withColumn('decimalval',ConvertToDec(col('salary'))) 
dframe.show()
```

Below is the output

```
+---------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
|firstName|lastName|         email|   salary| salaryday|finalname|decimalval|
+---------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
|      len|armbrust| bash@learn.co|  0012.75|2020-04-30|      len|        13|
|      dem|    meng|daniel@uda.edu|0013.2461|2020-04-30|      dem|        13|
+---------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

I have below problems 
 1) The decimal value instead of being **12.7590** and **13.2461** is being round of to  **13** 
 2)  if i change precession in UDF as DecimalType(4,4) i get below error

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2598.showString.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Decimal precision 6 exceeds max precision 4
```

How do i retain precision and how to retain precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `regexp_reaplace` first to move the `-` sign in front and then `cast` to `DecimalType`. Like that you avoid having to use a UDF. Something like this should work:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
...
dframe = dframe.withColumn(
    'decimalval',
    regexp_replace('salary', r'([0-9\.]+)\-', '-$1').cast("DECIMAL(8,4)"))
```

Note that given you have 8 digits in your decimal number you should use `DecimalType(8, 4)` and not `DecimalType(4, 4)`. From the pyspark doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=join#pyspark.sql.types.DecimalType)

```
precision – the maximum total number of digits (default: 10)

scale – the number of digits on right side of dot. (default: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks , Ur Solution worked  but sometimes i may get decimal value like 0909.8978 i man without - at end that time this return null i want value to be 0909.8978

Comment: the `regexp_replace` should work when there isn't a `-` as well. However you also need to make sure that the case would work. If it cannot be casted as a decimal you will end up with nulls.

Comment: since data had space , i was ending up with nulls. Thanks